# Post to Facebook wall from own application

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, authentication, feed

I have created a Facebook application under developers.facebook.com and would like to use it's access_token in order to post a message to my own feed:

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{fb_user_id}/feed?access_token=#{fb_access_token}"
```

However, Facebook seems to not recognize that this app is assigned to my account; the API responds with a OAuth 200, 'The user has not authorized this application to post....'

I do not want to ask any other users of my website to grant my application posting permissions, I just want to post to my *own* feed.

Is there an (easy) way to do this, I've read through the FB API documentation but haven't found it...

thx for any hints!

Answer (score 0):

"The user has not authorized this application to post." is a permissions error, it means you have granted access for you (the user) to use the app but the correct scope of permissions to post, specifically `publish_stream`

You can ensure you have this permission by checking

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?fields=publish_stream&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`

You should get a response similar to the following

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "publish_stream": 1
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?fields=publish_stream&limit=5000&offset=5000"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to just set the permission for my own user without having to present everybody else with that permissions popup after FB login?